# Как задать пользовательское свойство функции через обертку(wrapper)? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть некая функция `sum(a, b)`. Через функцию обертку (`wrapper(func)`) хочу добавить начальной функции пользовательское свойство `calls`, пусть это будет условный массив.
При добавлении этого свойства через `func.calls` или `this.calls` при вызове этого свойства выводит `undefined`. Почему так? Как задать это свойство через `wrapper(func)` правильно?

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  alert(a + b);
}

function wrapper(func) {
  return function(a, b) {
    //func.calls = [1,2,3];
    this.calls = [1, 2, 3]
    func(a, b);
  };
}

sum = wrapper(sum);

console.log(sum.calls); //undefined
```

Comment: добавляешь не туда, и не тогда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сразу установить поля для `func`, которая приходит на вход и его же вернуть:

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  console.log(a + b);
}

function wrapper(func) {
  func.calls = [1, 2, 3];
  
  return func;
}

sum = wrapper(sum);

console.log(sum.calls);
sum(1, 2);
```

Comment: @AleksandrVolkov Я чё-то не сразу додумался, можно намного проще сделать то что вам надо. Изменил ответ, используйте это вместо старого

Comment: спасибо большое! Подскажите еще, пожалуйста. Правильно ли я понимаю, что присвоение func.calls = [1, 2, 3] (по моему примеру - в вопросе) будет выполнено только после присвоения sum = wrapper(sum); и вызова sum(1, 2); Только тогда можно вызывать console.log(sum.calls); так как до [ присвоения sum = wrapper(sum); вызова sum(1, 2) ] свойства sum.calls не было создано. Но и в таком случае у меня свойство почему-то не присваивается.

Comment: @AleksandrVolkov У вас ф-ия ничего не возращает, даже если будет присвоено вы этого не сможете достать, т.к. сразу идёт вызов `func`. Вы можете написать так например `sum = new (wrapper(sum));`, чтобы получить экзмепляр обёртки, где уже будет то что вы поставили в `calls`